# Excel: MATCH() formulas with no wildcard matching

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I currently use `MATCH()` in Excel 2016 formula columns such as:

```
= MATCH( [@[ITEM_CODE]], IM_PURCH_VENDOR_SUBLIST[[#All],[ITEM-CODE]], 0 )
```

The result is essentially a foreign key. It is used in other columns with `INDEX()` or `OFFSET()` expressions to relate the current row to the matching row in the other table.

Some lookup values contain punctuation, including the special wildcard characters `*`, `?`, and `~`. This causes unintended matching. A real example is the item code `*XA1`, which unintentionally matches item code `1SC0021REXA1` in the other table.

My current solution for the example above is:

```
= MATCH(
SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( [@[ITEM_CODE]], "~", "~~" ), "*", "~*" ), "?", "~?" ),
IM_PURCH_VENDOR_SUBLIST[[#All],[ITEM-CODE]],
0
)
```

What don’t I like? It’s easy to forget when writing `INDEX(MATCH())` expressions, easy to get wrong (order matters), and just plain clunky and hard to read. But I have not found a non-wildcarding `MATCH()` alternative, or even a way to simplify the substitution expression, without creating more complexity elsewhere, such as writing a custom function in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregate:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(IM_PURCH_VENDOR_SUBLIST[[#All],[ITEM-CODE]])-MIN(ROW(IM_PURCH_VENDOR_SUBLIST[[#All],[ITEM-CODE]]))+1)/(IM_PURCH_VENDOR_SUBLIST[[#All],[ITEM-CODE]]=[@[ITEM_CODE]]),1)
```

[image]

Or you can use this array version of MATCH:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,[ITEM_CODE]=IM_PURCH_VENDOR_SUBLIST[[#All],[ITEM-CODE]],0)
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode.

[image]

This is the same as the second but does not require the need for CSE:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX([ITEM_CODE]=IM_PURCH_VENDOR_SUBLIST[[#All],[ITEM-CODE]],),0)
```

Comment: In the third expression, `[ITEM_CODE]=IM_PURCH_VENDOR_SUBLIST[[#All],[ITEM-CODE]]` looks to me like an array formula. But it doesn't require CSE?

Comment: Neither the first nor the third require CSE even though they are array type formulas.  They are native array formula.  There are a few of those; SUMPRODUCT,IRR,... and a few others.

Comment: Do you know where in the Microsoft docs I can find out which functions create this sort of array formula context?

Comment: No, I do not, sorry.  I learned them organically.